# map predefined words in a string into a hash in perl

Tags: regex, perl, hash

Basically I'm trying to take certain keywords in a string along with the accompanying text to be put in a hash.

A sample string:

```
!add-action-item :date 03/29/2012 :task Go to the bathroom :prio 1
```

Code snip:

```
when(/^!add-action-item/) {
        my ($date, $prio, $task) = $what =~ /:date\s(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\s|:prio\s(\d+)\s|:task\s(.*)/;
        print Dumper($date, $prio, $task);
    }
```

So basically I'd like to have predefined attributes like :date, :prio, :task and convert those into

```
%ash = ( date => $date,
         prio => $prio,
         task => $task
       )
```

Eventually I'd like to just accept any attribute and place into a key value pair and just act on the ones I care about. Im pretty noobish when it comes to perl so I apologize if this is something builtin I missed in the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like the idea of looking for specific fields in a specific order. mugen kenichi's solution will fail if a 4th field is added, for example.

Here's a more robust solution by virtue of being more generic:

```
my $cmd = '!add-action-item :date 03/29/2012 :task Go to the bathroom :prio 1';

for ($cmd) {
   /\G ! (\S+) /xgc or die;
   my $action = $1;

   my %args;
   for (;;) {
      last if /\G \s* \z /xgc;

      /\G \s+ :(\S+) /xgc or die;
      my $name = $1;

      /\G \s+ ([^\s:]\S*(?:\s+[^\s:]\S*)*) /xgc or die;
      my $val = $1;

      $args{$name} = $val;
   }

   # Do something with $action and %args here.
}
```

Alternative implementation:

```
my $cmd = '!add-action-item :date 03/29/2012 :task Go to the bathroom :prio 1';

{
   my ($action, @args) = split /\s+:/, $cmd;

   $action =~ s/^!//;
   $action =~ s/\s+\z//;

   my %args;
   for my $arg (@args) {
      my ($name, $val) = split(' ', $arg, 2);
      $args{$name} = $val;
   }

   # Do something with $action and %args here.
}
```

For example, if you use

```
use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );
local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
local $Data::Dumper::Terse  = 1;
printf("action: %s\n", $action);
printf("args:   %s\n", Dumper(\%args));
```

You get:

```
action: add-action-item
args:   {'date' => '03/29/2012','prio' => '1','task' => 'Go to the bathroom'}
```

---

[Parse::RecDescent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parse%3a%3aRecDescent) grammar (untested):

```
parse    : command /\Z/ { $item[1] }
command  : action arg(s) { [ $item[1], { map @$_, @{$item[2]} } ] }
action   : /!\S+/ { substr($item[1], 1) }
arg_name : /:\S+/ { substr($item[1], 1) }
arg_val  : /[^\s:]\S*(?:\s+[^\s:]\S*)*/
```

Comment: this one is more suitable to what I was looking for. thanks! it would be cool if there was something on cpan that mimicked this?

Comment: @battlemidget, A parser for an unnamed language?

Comment: i dunno i was thinking more of like a getopt type module that gave the ability to define key - value styles for strings of data. ive seen tokenizing type modules and perhaps those are what im referring to

Comment: @battlemidget, You underestimate the complexity of instructing code of the grammar of a language, but there is such a thing as a parser generator (e.g. [Parse::RecDescent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parse::RecDescent)). Added PRD grammar to answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can not capture all three groups using `|`.

Fix your regex and then build your data structure from the capturing groups.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $string = '!add-action-item :date 03/29/2012 :task Go to the bathroom :prio 1';

if ( $string =~ /^!add-action-item/ ) {
    $string =~ m[
        \s+:date\s(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})
        \s+:task\s(.*)
        \s+:prio\s(\d+)
    ]x;

    my $data = {
        date => $1,
        task => $2,
        prio => $3,
    };

    print Dumper $data;
}

__END__

$VAR1 = {
      'date' => '03/29/2012',
      'prio' => '1',
      'task' => 'Go to the bathroom'
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
use Data::Dumper;
my @array = qw(Today stat bigone);
my %hash;
@hash{qw( date prio task )} = @array;
print Dumper \%hash;

$VAR1 = {
          'date' => 'Today',
          'prio' => 'stat',
          'task' => 'bigone'
        };
```

Comment: It actually answeres the question but i guess the op just asked the wrong one.